Structural Induction Proof for Recursive Functions on Boolean Expressions
I'm working on a set of problems in my logic course, where we're dealing with recursive functions that count specific types of subexpressions in Boolean expressions. Here’s the context from the previous problems, which define the functions I need to use for the proof in Problem 3.
Some background
We defined a recursive function called countbinexprs. This function takes a Boolean expression and returns the count of binary subexpressions of the form $ BExpr \land BExpr $ or $ BExpr \lor BExpr $ within the expression. The task was to evaluate this function on a specific expression:
$$
((\text{bool} \land (\text{bool} \lor \text{bool})) \land (\lnot \text{bool}))
$$
For this input, countbinexprs should return 3, since there are three binary operations ($\land$ and $\lor$) in the expression.
We then defined a second recursive function called countexprs. This function counts all subexpressions within a Boolean expression, including atomic expressions (like bool), negations, and binary expressions. Even single elements, such as bool, are considered subexpressions, and nested subexpressions are counted as well. For the same expression from Problem 1, countexprs should return 8, reflecting all the subexpressions within the Boolean expression.
The problem
Now, I need to prove that for any Boolean expression $ b $, the inequality $$ \text{countbinexprs}(b) \leq \text{countexprs}(b) $$ holds. I believe this involves using structural induction based on the recursive structure of $ b $. However, I’m struggling with setting up the induction hypothesis correctly and understanding how to handle each type of subexpression (atomic expressions, negations, and binary operations) in the induction step.
If anyone has insights on setting up the structural induction proof or handling the cases for binary and non-binary subexpressions in this context, I'd really appreciate the help!
Edit: My attempt
After receiving some guidance, I’ve tried to set up the proof using structural induction. Here’s what I have so far:
Base Case
Consider the simplest Boolean expression, which is an atomic expression like bool. In this case:

countbinexprs(bool) = 0 because there are no binary operations (no ∧ or ∨).
countexprs(bool) = 1 because the expression itself is counted as a single subexpression.

Since $ 0 \leq 1 $, the base case holds.
Induction Step
Now, assume that the inequality $ countbinexprs(b) \leq countexprs(b) $ holds for any Boolean subexpressions of $ b $. We will prove that the inequality holds for more complex expressions by considering two cases based on the structure of $ b $:

Case 1: Negation (e.g., $ b = \lnot b_1 $)


countbinexprs(b) is equal to countbinexprs(b1) because adding a negation doesn’t introduce any new binary expressions.
countexprs(b) is equal to countexprs(b1) + 1 to account for the additional ¬ operation.

Since adding a negation doesn’t increase countbinexprs, and it only adds 1 to countexprs, the inequality still holds.

Case 2: Conjunction or Disjunction (e.g., $ b = b_1 \land b_2 $ or $ b = b_1 \lor b_2 $)


countbinexprs(b) = countbinexprs(b1) + countbinexprs(b2) + 1, as the new binary operation (either ∧ or ∨) adds 1 to the total count.
countexprs(b) = countexprs(b1) + countexprs(b2) + 1, since each subexpression in b1 and b2 is counted, and the new binary operation also adds 1 to countexprs.

By the induction hypothesis, we know that $ countbinexprs(b_1) \leq countexprs(b_1) $ and $ countbinexprs(b_2) \leq countexprs(b_2) $. Adding 1 on both sides maintains the inequality, so $ countbinexprs(b) \leq countexprs(b) $ still holds.
Conclusion
By structural induction, we’ve shown that $ countbinexprs(b) \leq countexprs(b) $ for all Boolean expressions $ b $.

This is your third question on the same topic. The same comments as previously apply. What have you tried? What are you stuck on.

@NaïmFavier I’m honestly struggling to approach this proof using structural induction. I understand that I need to show the inequality for all Boolean expressions
b, but I’m not sure how to properly set up the induction, especially how to handle the different types of subexpressions (like atomic expressions, negations, and binary expressions) within this framework.
If anyone could guide me on how to begin structuring this proof or explain the general approach to using structural induction in this context, it would be incredibly helpful. Thank you!

@MauroALLEGRANZA So you're suggesting I start out with a base case, where the number of binary expressions (countbinexprs) is 0 because there are no binary operations, then the number of all subexpressions (countexprs) is 1, accounting for the atomic element itself. For the induction step, we handle different types of Boolean expressions. As you suggest, we divide this into two main sub-cases:

Sub-case (i): If the expression is a negation (e.g., ¬b), then:
(1) The total count of subexpressions (countexprs) increases by 1 to include the negation. (2) The count of binary expressions (countbinexprs) remains the same, as negation isn’t a binary operation.
Sub-case (ii): If the expression is a conjunction or disjunction (e.g., b1 ∧ b2 or b1 ∨ b2), then both b1 and b2 are themselves Boolean expressions. In this case:

(3) The count of binary expressions increases by 1 for the new conjunction or disjunction.
(4) The total count of subexpressions also increases, so the inequality is preserved.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I've showed my attempt at the bottom of the forum post, would you say that aligns with what you suggested? Do you agree with the solution I provided?

Yes, your final attempt is correct.
Structural Induction is not different form the usual Mathematical Induction.
Usually, you have to consider several sub-cases. In this problem, the Base step of the proof must consider a formula with only one atom, in wich case the number of binary expressions [binary connectives] is $0$ and the number of expressions is $1$.
Then the Induction step follows, with sub-case (i) the negation of an expression, in which case the number of expressions increase by one and the number of binary expressions does not change, and sub-case (ii) the conjunction (disjunction) of two expressions, that is similar.
